# MatSort not sorting data in MatTable using Angular 8

Tags: angular, angular-material, angular8, mat-table

I have a new angular project in Angular 8 and I'm having issues with getting the MatSort to actually sort the data in a MatTable.

Here is a simplified version of my `component.ts` file:

```
import {
  AfterViewInit,
  Component,
  OnInit,
  ViewChild,
} from "@angular/core";
import { MatSort } from "@angular/material/sort";
import { MatTableDataSource } from "@angular/material/table";
import { IEmployeeInterface } from "../somepath/employee.interface";
import { EmployeeQueryService } from "../../somepath/employeequery.service";

@Component({
  styleUrls: ["./employeedetails.component.scss"],
  templateUrl: "./employeedetails.component.html"
})
export class TestQueryComponent implements OnInit, AfterViewInit {
    employeeItems: IEmployeeInterface[];
    employeeData: new MatTableDataSource<IEmployeeInterface>();

    employeeColumns = [
    "EmployeeName",
    "EmployeeAddress",
    "EmployeeSalary"
    ];

    @ViewChild(MatSort, {static: false}) sort: MatSort;

    constructor(private employeeQueryService: EmployeeQueryService) {
    /* OTHER CODE HERE */
    }

    ngOnInit() {
        this.getEmployeeData();
    }

   ngAfterViewInit() {
    this.employeeData.sort = this.sort;
  }

  private getEmployeeData() {
    this.employeeQueryService.getEmployeeData().subscribe(response => {
      this.employeeItems = response;
      this.employeeData.data = this.employeeItems;
    });
  }
}
```

and my `html` file looks something like this:

```
<table mat-table [dataSource]="employeeData" matSort>
    <ng-container matColumnDef="EmployeeName">
      <th mat-header-cell *matHeaderCellDef mat-sort-header="EmployeeName"> Employee</th>
      <td mat-cell *matCellDef="let element">{{element.employeeName}}</td>
    </ng-container>
    <ng-container matColumnDef="EmployeeAddress">
      <th mat-header-cell *matHeaderCellDef mat-sort-header="EmployeeAddress"> Employee Address/th>
      <td mat-cell *matCellDef="let element">{{element.employeeAddress}}</td>
    </ng-container>
    <ng-container matColumnDef="EmployeeSalary">
      <th mat-header-cell *matHeaderCellDef mat-sort-header="EmployeeSalary">Employee Salary </th>
      <td mat-cell *matCellDef=" let element">{{element.employeeSalary | currency}}</td>
    </ng-container>
    <tr mat-header-row *matHeaderRowDef="employeeColumns; sticky: true"></tr>
    <tr mat-row *matRowDef="let row; columns: employeeColumns;"></tr>
</table>
```

I have a couple of comments about this.

1. When running this, there are no console errors being thrown in the browser.
2. I have an older app running on Angular 7 very similar to this with the major difference being `@ViewChild(MatSort, {static: false}) sort: MatSort;` was simply `@ViewChild(MatSort) sort: MatSort;` and the sorting is working as expected in the Angular 7 app.
3. I have the following in `app.module.ts` :

   ````
   import { MatSortModule } from "@angular/material/sort";
   @NgModule({...
   exports: [
   MatSortModule,
   ...],
   imports: [
   MatSortModule
   ]})```
   ````

I have also tried the following variation in the component file without any luck:

```
ngAfterViewInit() {

  }

  private getEmployeeData() {
    this.employeeQueryService.getEmployeeData().subscribe(response => {
      this.employeeItems = response;
      this.employeeData.data = this.employeeItems;
      this.employeeData.sort = this.sort;
    });
  }
```

Additionally if I include this:

```
ngAfterViewInit() {
  this.employeeData.sort = this.sort;
  this.sort.sortChange.subscribe(x => console.log(x, this.employeeData.sort));
  }
```

Everytime I click try and sort a column I can see that it appears to be sorting: `{active:"EmployeeName", direction:"asc"}` and that the MatSort object has the correct `sortables` and the `_direction` property is correct.

What could be happening here?  Thanks

Comment: You should leave it in **AfterViewInit** or reconstruct your logic. 

When you assign `this.sort` in **OnInit**, it is still `undefined`, because component template is not yet initialised.

Answer (score 2):

I figured it out. The `mat-sort-header` property in the `<th>` tag is case sensitive. As an example:

```
<ng-container matColumnDef="EmployeeName">
   <th mat-header-cell *matHeaderCellDef mat-sort-header="EmployeeName"> Employee</th>
   <td mat-cell *matCellDef="let element">{{element.employeeName}}</td>
</ng-container>
```

needed to be this:

```
<ng-container matColumnDef="EmployeeName">
       <th mat-header-cell *matHeaderCellDef mat-sort-header="employeeName"> Employee</th>
       <td mat-cell *matCellDef="let element">{{element.employeeName}}</td>
    </ng-container>
```

There goes 3-4 hours of my life I will never get back.

Answer (score 0):

I had a similar problem and solved it by always generating a new `MatTableDataSource` when getting new data.

```
private getEmployeeData() {
    this.employeeQueryService.getEmployeeData().subscribe(response => {
      this.employeeItems = response;
      this.employeeData.data = new MatTableDataSource<IEmployeeInterface>(this.employeeItems);
      if(this.sort) {
        this.employeeData.sort = this.sort;
      }
    });
  }
```

If your table isn't rendered at the start of your component because it's wrapped in a `ngIf` you can define a setter method for `MatSort`.

```
@ViewChild(MatSort, {static: false})set matSort(ms: MatSort) {
  if(this.employeeData) {
    this.employeeData.sort = ms;
  }
};
```

Comment: Thank-you for your response. I tried your suggestion but I still have the same problem.